# PowerShell "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "Object[]" to type "array""

Tags: powershell, virtualbox

Since the new virtualbox update to 6.1 I'm having some problems with the pxe file for creating virtual machines.

Here's the error I'm getting while running the pxe.

```
Exception setting "LaunchVMProcess": Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "Object[]" to type "array".
+ $vm.LaunchVMProcess($vsession, "", "") | Out-Null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Below are some of these variables opened for better understanding.

```
$vbox = New-Object -ComObject "VirtualBox.VirtualBox"
$vm = $vbox.CreateMachine($sname, $vmname, [string[]]@(""), "Ubuntu_64", "forceOverwrite=1")

$vsession = New-Object -ComObject "VirtualBox.Session"
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://www.virtualbox.org/sdkref/interface_i_machine.html), the third parameter `environmentChanges` should be a list of strings. An empty list is allowed. Have you tried `$vm.LaunchVMProcess($vsession, "", [string[]]@())`

Comment: That solved it, thank you!